# Angular primeng fullcalendar handle change date of event

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, primeng

I want to handle event when I change the date of event. I want to get new date in function. is it possible to do this?

e.g. I have event on 2020-01-01 and I drag and drop to date 2020-01-10 and I want to take event of this move. is it possible to do this in angular 8 with primeng?

```
<p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the `eventDrop` callback:

```js
options {
  eventDrop: eventDropInfo => {
    const { event } = eventDropInfo;
    // Your code
  }
}
```

[Learn more info about this event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop) and learn more about all options in [fullcalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs)